# c programming try to get enum word in scanf and put it in int array

Tags: c

I try to run this program and use the enum to get a string from the user and put it in A array as a int 
the problme is that when i try to get with scanf the data from the user , than instead of runing the program  by  its gump forward

this is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 


int main()
{
    enum color { RED = 1, BLUE, BLACK };
char choice[6];
int colors[21];
int  i, counter_red = 0, counter_blue = 0, counter_black = 0, x;


for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    printf("Write your favorite color : RED, BLUE or BLACK\n");
    scanf_s("%s", &choice);


    if (strcmp(choice, "BLACK") == 0)
    {
        colors[i] = 3;
    }

    if (strcmp(choice, "BLUE") == 0)
    {
        colors[i] = 2;
    }

    if (strcmp(choice, "RED") == 0)
    {
        colors[i] = 1;
    }



}


for (x = 0; x < 20; x++)
{
    if (colors[x] == 1)
    {
        counter_red++;
    }
    else if (colors[x] == 2)
    {
        counter_blue++;
    }
    else if (colors[x] == 3)
    {
        counter_black++;
    }
}
if (counter_red > counter_blue && counter_red > counter_black)
{
    printf("%s", "The most popular color is: RED\n");
}
else if (counter_blue > counter_red && counter_blue > counter_black)
{
    printf("%s", "The most popular color is: BLUE\n");
}
else if (counter_black > counter_red && counter_blue < counter_black)
{
    printf("%s", "The most popular color is: BLACK\n");
}
printf("RED: %d % \nBLUE: %d %\nBLACK : %d % \n", counter_red * 5, counter_blue * 5, counter_black * 5);


return 0;

}
```

Comment: I recommend learning C basics first, there are quite a few C tutorials online, just Google.

Answer (score 0):

You're using [`scanf_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) wrong. First of all the array `choice` decays to a pointer when passing it to a function, so you should not use the address-of operator `&` there. Secondly, and more importantly, for each format code in the format string, [`scanf_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) expects *two* arguments: The destination of the conversion, and the size of the destination.

Since you don't pass the size, you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) when the `scanf_s` function tries to fetch that value of the stack.

Your call should look like

```
scanf_s("%s", choice, sizeof(choice));
```

---

As a side-note: You don't actually *use* the enumeration you define. To use it you should do e.g.

```
...
enum color colors[20];
...
colors[i] = RED;
```

As another side-note: You only use 20 entries in the `colors` array, but you define it as 21 entries.

Comment: thank you very nuch p.s i forced to use scanf_s becoas im using vs... p.s.2 if i dont use scanf_s did i steal need to do it like this?    scanf("%s", choice, sizeof(choice)); ? or i need to do it back like this scanf("%s", &choice);?

Comment: @H_meir The plain `scanf` doesn't use the size argument, and you still should not use the address-of operator `&` on arrays (or pointers) for strings.